# Improving MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two MongoDB collections: one holds data for some products, the other holds data for some categories. What I'm trying to do is this: given a category get all related products to that, by looking at it's sub categories. Essentially I'm trying to get the category tree to get all the related product pages. So, I have the category document which looks like this

```
_id: "cat-id",
"url": /cat-1",
childs: [
   {"position": 1, "childs": [
         {"category": "sub-category-1-id", "productPage": ""},
         {"category": "sub-category-2-id", "productPage": ""}
      ]
   },
   {"position": 2, "childs": [
         {"category": "", "productPage": "product-page-1-id"},
         {"category": "", "productPage": "product-page-2-id"}
      ]
   }
],
"links": [
   {"position": 0, "url": "/related-category-1-url"},
   {"position": 1, "url": "/related-category-2-url"}
],
"productPages":[
   {"position": 0, "productPage": "product-page-1-id"}, 
   {"position": 1, "productPage": "product-page-2-id"}
]
```

From each category I take the `productPages` array if has some values, so I get the directly linked pages to that category. Next I recursively get all the related categories and the child categories until the subcategory is a leaf or a subcategory child has the productPage field not empty (the problem here is this: a category could be a leaf but in it's parent can show other subcategories... I know, it's weird and probably wrong but I didn't decided this structure...).

What I've done is an aggregation on MongoDB between the Category collection and the ProductPages collection. The aggregation itself works, however for big categories (let's say categories that has 50 childs, and each of them has other 30 child categories, and so on...) the query takes too much time, sometimes it takes even minutes before eventually crashing... This is the aggregation I use right now

```
db.getCollection('Categories').aggregate([
    {$match: { "url": "/cat-1"}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$links", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$links.values", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childs", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childs.childs", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "ProductPages",
        startWith: "$productPages.productPage",
        connectFromField: "productPages.productPage",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "rootPages"
    }},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "ProductPages",
        startWith: "$childs.childs.productPage",
        connectFromField: "childs.childs.productPage",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "childPages"
    }},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "Categories",
        startWith: "$links.values.url",
        connectFromField: "links.values.url",
        connectToField: "url",
        as: "linkCategories"
    }},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "Categories",
        startWith: "$childs.url",
        connectFromField: "childs.url",
        connectToField: "url",
        as: "childUrlCategories"
    }},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "Categories",
        startWith: "$childs.childs.category",
        connectFromField: "childs.childs.category",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "childCategories"
    }},
    {$unwind: {path: "$linkCategories", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childUrlCategories", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childCategories", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childCategories.childs", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childCategories.childs.childs", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "ProductPages",
        startWith: "$linkCategories.productPages.productPage",
        connectFromField: "linkCategories.productPages.productPage",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "linkPages"
    }},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "ProductPages",
        startWith: "$childUrlCategories.productPages.productPage",
        connectFromField: "childUrlCategories.productPages.productPage",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "childUrlPages"
    }},
    {$graphLookup: {
        from: "ProductPages",
        startWith: "$childCategories.childs.childs.productPage",
        connectFromField: "childCategories.childs.childs.productPage",
        connectToField: "_id",
        as: "childCategoryPages"
    }},
    {$unwind: {path: "$rootPages", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$linkPages", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childUrlPages", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childPages", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$childCategoryPages", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$group: {_id: "", 
        rootPages: {$addToSet: "$rootPages"}, 
        linkPages: {$addToSet: "$linkPages"}, 
        childUrlPages: {$addToSet: "$childUrlPages"},
        childPages: {$addToSet: "$childPages"},
        childCategoryPages: {$addToSet: "$childCategoryPages"}
    }},
    {$project: {_id: 0, 
        rootPages: {_id: 1, product: 1}, 
        linkPages: {_id: 1, product: 1}, 
        childUrlPages: {_id: 1, product: 1}, 
        childPages: {_id: 1, product: 1},
        childCategoryPages: {_id: 1, product: 1}
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        "childCategoryPages": {
            $map: {
                "input": "$childCategoryPages",
                "as": "el",
                "in": "$$el.product"
            }
        }
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        "childPages": {
            $map: {
                "input": "$childPages",
                "as": "el",
                "in": "$$el.product"
            }
        }
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        "childUrlPages": {
            $map: {
                "input": "$childUrlPages",
                "as": "el",
                "in": "$$el.product"
            }
        }
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        "linkPages": {
            $map: {
                "input": "$linkPages",
                "as": "el",
                "in": "$$el.product"
            }
        }
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        "rootPages": {
            $map: {
                "input": "$rootPages",
                "as": "el",
                "in": "$$el.product"
            }
        }
    }},
    {$project: {products: {$concatArrays: ["$rootPages", "$linkPages", "$childUrlPages", "$childPages", "$childCategoryPages"]}}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$products", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$group: {
        _id: "",
        products: {$addToSet: "$products"}
    }},
    {$project: {_id: 0, products: 1}},
]);
```

As I said, for small categories this works, but for large ones is really really slow (the productPages, links, url and childs fields are already indexes, if you wonder). So how can I improve this query to make it work for large categories too?

EDIT: This is a sample ProductPage document (from which in aggregation I take the product field)

```
_id: "product-page-1-id",
url: "/page-1",
product: "product-1"
```

The aggregation result is an array of products taken from the retrieved pages, which looks like this

```
["product-1", "product-2", ...]
```

Comment: Make sure all `connectToField: field_name` are indexed in their collections (except _id, it's aleady indexed by default). Also, post here `ProductPages` sample to take a look

Comment: Also, post desired result. I think `$facet` is more elegant solution

Comment: I've added the productPages and result to the question. I was also thinking about splitting the aggregation in multiple pipelines, but I'm worried it will still be slow when doing the recursive part (since if I exclude the `childs` related parts from the pipeline everything is fast, even for large categories)

Comment: Please share in MongoPlayground full data for `"url": "/cat-1"` (real data with sub-category, etc...) like shown here [https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vg0V9hmJ705](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vg0V9hmJ705) and we can see how to improve performance. Since `links.values` doesn't exist and not clear why you need to use `$graphLookup` if your expected result is plain array...

Comment: I'll try to add it to mongoplayground, but in the mean time I've come up with this solution which seems to work for big categories as well
[https://pastebin.com/bVmSCrCj](https://pastebin.com/bVmSCrCj)

Comment: You may setup `{$match: { "url": "/cat-1"}}` as 1st stage and then define`$facet`, so you do not need to retireve same data for each facets. (you can omit redundant code + improve 0.01ms performance)